# Show that Polar of a set is convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-cone

Polar of a set is defined as:

$C^0 = \{ y\in \mathbb{R}^n | y^Tx \leq 1, \forall x \in C\}$

Now from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_cone_and_polar_cone), the intuitive idea of polar of a cone is easily understandable. But how can it be shown that $C^0$ is convex, even when $C$ is not? 
 Any hint or explanation is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $y^T x \leq 0$ rather than $y^T x \leq 1$? See the section called "Polar cone" in the Wikipedia article linked to.

Answer (score 5):

$C^0$ can be written as the intersection of closed half-spaces:
$$
C^0 = \bigcap_{x\in C} \{ y\in \mathbb R^n: x^Ty\le 1\},
$$
hence $C^0$ is convex.

If $C$ is cone then
$$
C^0 = \{ y\in \mathbb R^n: x^Ty\le 0 \ \forall x\in C\},
$$
which is sometimes called the dual cone.
If $C$ is a linear subspace then $C^0 = C^\perp$.

Comment: Is your notation correct? Could you please explain a little bit more? For example, if $C$ is a cone, then what will be the $C^0$? I am trying to get the intuitive idea here.

Comment: What are your doubts? You could also check convexity directly, after all, the conditions in $C^0$ are affine linear inequalities.

Comment: I was wondering if its $x^Ty$ or $y^Tx$ as you wrote above?

Answer (score 0):

The half-space proof by daw is quick and elegant; here is also a direct proof:

Let $\alpha\in\left]0,1\right[$, let $x\in C$, and let $y_1,y_2\in C^0$. Then by definition of $C^0$, $y_1^\top x\leq 1$ and $y_2^\top x\leq 1$. Since multiplication by positive numbers preserves inequality, we know $\alpha y_1^\top x\leq \alpha$ and $(1-\alpha)y_2^\top x\leq (1-\alpha)$. Adding both inequalities reveals
$$\alpha y_1^\top x+(1-\alpha)y_2^\top x=\big(\alpha y_1+(1-\alpha)y_2\big)^\top x\leq \alpha+(1-\alpha)=1,$$
so $\alpha y_1+(1-\alpha)y_2\in C^0$ which completes the proof.